# Saxon can't find package

Tags: saxon, xslt-3.0

I encounter some difficulties when using packages with Saxon 9.8. Saxon can't find the package I want to use and fail at compilation.

When using the `-lib` option from the command line, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.sf.saxon.style.PackageVersion.<init>(PackageVersion.java:71)
        at net.sf.saxon.trans.packages.VersionedPackageName.<init>(VersionedPackageName.java:29)
        at net.sf.saxon.trans.packages.PackageInspector.getNameAndVersion(PackageInspector.java:78)
        at et.sf.saxon.trans.packages.PackageInspector.getPackageDetails(PackageInspector.java:91)
        at net.sf.saxon.trans.packages.PackageLibrary.<init>(PackageLibrary.java:96)
        at net.sf.saxon.Transform.doTransform(Transform.java:404)
        at net.sf.saxon.Transform.main(Transform.java:81) Fatal error during transformation: java.lang.NullPointerException:  (no message)
```

When using `-lib` option in oXygen 19 with the Saxon 9.8 add-on, I get the following message:

```
Nom du moteur: Saxon-EE 9.8.0.4 (External)
Gravité: fatal
Description: Cannot find package img_pkg (version *)
Emplacement de début: 7:52
```

I get exactly the same error message in oXygen when I use a configuration file to declare the package.

I'm pretty sure that there is no problem with the file path. Since in the error message I get in oXygen the package version doesn't seem to be recognized, I thought it could be a syntax problem but I can't find where it comes from.

Here is test my package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:package name="img_pkg" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:img="https://www.ephe.fr/annuaire/colin-brisson"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs img" version="1.0">

    <xsl:function name="img:test" visibility="final" as="xs:string">
       <xsl:value-of select="'test ok'"/>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:package>
```

Here's my test sylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:img="https://www.ephe.fr/annuaire/colin-brisson" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:use-package version="1.0" name="img_pkg"/>

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">

        <xsl:message>
            <xsl:value-of select="img:test()"/>
        </xsl:message>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us your command line when you get that exception?

Comment: Thank you for your response @MartinHonnen. My command is `java -cp C:\SaxonEE9-8-0-3J\saxon9ee.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -lib:img_pkg.xsl -xsl:test.xsl -it`. The package and the stylesheet are both in the working directory.

Comment: What happens when you donate your `xsl:package` an explicit `package-version` attribute?

Comment: It works from the command line but I get the same error under oXygen.

Comment: How you set up that `-lib` option exactly in oXygen? It sounds as if it is not used or recognized as it indicates it doesn't find the package.

Comment: I add it in the transformation scenario parameters. I tried with the absolute path, relative path, and editor variables, nothing worked. I always get the same `Cannot find package img_pkg (version *)`, even after adding the package-version attribute.

Comment: I don't think oXygen does allow you to use Saxon command line options as a transformation parameter. You might want to ask in their support forum on how to set it up to use packages.

Comment: I think version="1.0" on xsl:package should be package-version="1.0". @version is the XSLT version and should be "3.0". But I don't think that's the main cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the NullPointerException from the command line is due to bug 3373

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3373

although in your case the root cause is a little different from that in the bug entry, it's the absence of a package-version attribute. This is fixed in 9.8.0.4, but from the line numbers in the stack trace it looks to me as if you are using an earlier maintenance release.

The problem in oXygen is probably completely different, but it might again be related to the absence of @package-version.